# Accepting a parameter either as individual object or as array of objects

Tags: ruby, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a bunch of functions that take in either an array of objects, or a single object designed to be treated as an array containing one object, and I am looking for a cleaner way to accomplish this. Basically, I want to know how I could make the `unless` part in the following function more concise:

```
def foo(bar_or_bars)
  unless bar_or_bars.is_a?(Array)
    bar_or_bars = [bar_or_bars]
  end
  bar_or_bars.each { |baz| ... }
end
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First thing you could do is to write the `unless` logic in a single line:

```
bars = bar_or_bars.is_a?(Array) ? bar_or_bars : [bar_or_bars]
```

As you see, I give it a new name here, as it's no longer a bar or bars, it's now definitely a collection.

The problem with this and your original approach is that although your function could work on any `Enumerable`, you will force your users to give you an argument of a specific type, which breaks duck typing.

A neat trick to partially solve that issue is the following:

```
def foo(bar_or_bars)
  bars = [*bar_or_bars]
  bars.each { |baz| ... }
end
```

I wouldn't exactly call that readable, though. It actually smells a lot like bad API design. Probably you should better take multiple arguments like this:

```
def foo(*bars)
  bars.each { |baz| ... }
end
```

And let the caller decide whether he wants to pass a single object or an array:

```
foo("XYZ")
ary = ["abc", "def"]
foo(*ary)
```

Comment: Thanks, that second trick was what I was looking for. I know its not ideal, but I actually oversimplified: since I have many consecutive parameters that behave like I described, I couldn't use just the plain old splat in the parameter list.

Answer (score 25):

The simplest solution is to use Kernel method [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#Array-method):

```
Array(5) #=> [5]
Array([1, 2, 3]) #=> [1,2,3]
```

so

```
def foo(bar_or_bars)
  Array(bar_or_bars).each { |bar| ... }
```

This will even work on nested arrays that have arrays as elements (they wont be flattened out).

One case this won't work for is Hashes:

```
Array(a: 1, b: 2) #=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
```

If you want to iterate through unchanged Hash objects, best use [Array.wrap](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/Array.wrap) from ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using this:

```
bars = [bar_or_bars].flatten
```